# My callback webhook is overloaded - what can I do?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I use an API to synchronise a lot of data to my app every night. The API itself uses a callback system, so I send a request to their API (including a webhook URL) and when the data is ready they will send a notification to my webhook to tell me to query the API again for the data.

The problem is, these callbacks flood in at a high rate (thousands per minute) to my webhook, which puts an awful lot of strain on my Flask web app (hosted on a Heroku dyno) and causes errors for end users. The webhook itself has been reduced down to forwarding the message on to a RabbitMQ queue (running on separate dynos), which then works through them progressively at its own pace. Unfortunately, this does not seem to be enough.

Is there something else I can do to manage this load? Is it possible to run a particular URL (or set of URLs) on a separate dyno from the public facing parts of the app? i.e. having two web dynos?

Thanks

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling

Comment: I have autoscaling via HireFire setup for my app already, but scaling the web dyno for what is essentially a worker task feels sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy you application with SAME code on more than one dyno using free tier. For example, you application is called rob1 and hosted at https://rob1.herokuapp.com, and source code accessible from https://git.heroku.com/rob1.git. You can create application rob2, accessible from  https://rob2.herokuapp.com and with source code hosted at https://git.heroku.com/rob2.git

Than, you can push code to 2nd application.

```sh
$ cd projects/bob1
$ git remote add heroku2 https://git.heroku.com/rob2.git 
$ git push heroku2 master
```

As result, you have single repo on your machine, and 2 identical heroku applications running code of your project. Probably, you'll need to copy environment parameters of 1st app to 2nd one.

But anyway, you'll have 2 identical apps on free tier.

Later, if you have obtained domain name, for example `robsapp.example.org`, you can make it have to CNAME DNS records pointing to your heroku apps to make load balancing like this

```
rob1.herokuapp.com
rob2.herokuapp.com
```

as result, you have you application webhooks available on `robsapp.example.org`  and it automatically load balance requests between rob1 and rob2 apps